# Semiring axioms which almost implement inverse, searching for domains other than lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, semirings, linear-logic

I'm working with an idempotent semiring which contains elements $C_i, \hat{C_i}$ with the following properties:

$$ {C}_i \hat{C_j} = 0 \quad\text{where}\quad i \neq j \quad\quad\quad\quad(\beta_0)$$
$$ {C}_i \hat{C_i} = 1 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\;\;(\beta_1)$$
$$ \sum_i \hat{C_i} {C}_i = 1 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(\eta) $$

As we see $\hat{C_i}$ is close to but not quite an inverse $C_i^{-1}$.

**Question:**  *What are the other fields of math where such or similar equations hold?*

---

*Wider context.*
A more complete set of equations would be:

$$ {C}^v_i \hat{C_j^v} = 0 \quad\text{where}\quad i \neq j \quad\quad\quad\quad(\beta_0)$$
$$ {C}^v_i \hat{C_i^v} = 1 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\;\;(\beta_1)$$
$$ \sum_i \hat{C_i^v} {C}^v_i = 1 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(\eta) $$
$$ {C}^v_i \hat{C_j^w} = \hat{C_j^w} {C}^v_i  \quad\text{where}\quad v \neq w  \quad \quad (\text{mpx})$$

In my case this semi-ring values and equations are related to lambda calculus where $v$ is a type and $i$ is (part of) a constructor and destructor. First and second equality corresponds to $\beta-$reduction and the third one to $\eta-$reduction.
For instance, we represent pair as:
$(a,b)=a \cdot C^\text{pair}_\text{fst} + b \cdot C^\text{pair}_\text{snd}$

- $\beta-$reduction: $(a,b)\cdot\hat{C}^\text{pair}_\text{snd} = b$
- $\eta-$reduction: $(a,b)\cdot \hat{C}^\text{pair}_\text{fst}\cdot{C}^\text{pair}_\text{fst} + (a,b)\cdot \hat{C}^\text{pair}_\text{snd}\cdot{C}^\text{pair}_\text{snd} = (a,b)$

$C^\lambda_\text{argument}, C^\lambda_\text{return}$ is implementing $\beta\eta-$reduction for linear function types.
And $C^{mpx}_1, \ldots, C^{mpx}_n$ together with semi-ring distributivity is implementing lambda term copying ([multiplexing](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/soft+linear+logic)).

This equations are a part of lambda calculus *Context Semantics* and also part of *Geometry Of Interaction* which are used to analyze computation behavior of *Sharing Graphs* a.k.a. *Interaction Nets*.

I also [asked this question on math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730829/help-with-identification-of-a-semiring-with-an-almost-inverse) but with a little success.
Thank you for any and all leads!

Comment: Dmitri answer made me think that the set $i$ can be thought of as basis of a some space where $C_i$ is a basis vector embedding and $\hat{C_i} is a projection$, so $\eta$ can be thought of as 'if we project to all bases and then recombine back we get the original object again'. But I'm not sure how to formalize it or how we could have more than one "independent" (i, j, ...) basis.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sort of strained example but there is certain resemblance to differential operators:

Let $i=0\dots p-2$ and $\mathbb F_p[x_0,\dots x_{p-2}]$ the algebra of polynomials over a finite field.

Define $C_i:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and $\hat C_i:=x_i$. That is, these are operators of differentiation and multiplication by $x_i$ on $\mathbb F_p[x_0,\dots x_{p-2}]$ (they are related to the creation/annihilation operators of quantum mechanics). One has the following relations:

$[C_i,\hat C_i]=1$

$[\hat C_i,C_i]=-1$ hence $\sum_{i=0}^{p-2}[\hat C_i, C_i]=1$

everything else commutes.